# SecurityException when trying to start an intent, by opening a Google+ link

Tags: android, google-plus

```
findPreference("app_credit").setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse("https://plus.google.com/XXX"));
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.open_with)));
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Permission(s) i use:
    android.permission.INTERNET

I'm using this in my Settings of the App to call a Google+ link from my app. Until it opens the chooser everything works but there only the options "Browser" works, when i click on "Google+" it crashes and the Logcat writes:

```
06-01 20:58:47.344: E/AndroidRuntime(19920): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-01 20:58:47.344: E/AndroidRuntime(19920): Process: com.XXX.todo, PID: 19920
06-01 20:58:47.344: E/AndroidRuntime(19920): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission         Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=https://plus.google.com/+XXX flg=0x3000000 cmp=com.google.android.apps.plus/com.google.android.libraries.social.gateway.GatewayActivity } from ProcessRecord{42d70208 19920:com.XXX.todo/u0a226} (pid=19920, uid=10226) not exported from uid 10066
06-01 20:58:47.344: E/AndroidRuntime(19920):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1465)
06-01 20:58:47.344: E/AndroidRuntime(19920):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1419)
06-01 20:58:47.344: E/AndroidRuntime(19920):    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:2096)
06-01 20:58:47.344: E/AndroidRuntime(19920):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1419)
06-01 20:58:47.344: E/AndroidRuntime(19920):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
06-01 20:58:47.344: E/AndroidRuntime(19920):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
06-01 20:58:47.344: E/AndroidRuntime(19920):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3627)
06-01 20:58:47.344: E/AndroidRuntime(19920):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3595)
06-01 20:58:47.344: E/AndroidRuntime(19920):    at com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity.onIntentSelected(ResolverActivity.java:408)
06-01 20:58:47.344: E/AndroidRuntime(19920):    at com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity.startSelected(ResolverActivity.java:300)
06-01 20:58:47.344: E/AndroidRuntime(19920):    at com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity.onItemClick(ResolverActivity.java:284)
06-01 20:58:47.344: E/AndroidRuntime(19920):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
06-01 20:58:47.344: E/AndroidRuntime(19920):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
06-01 20:58:47.344: E/AndroidRuntime(19920):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2904)
06-01 20:58:47.344: E/AndroidRuntime(19920):    at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3638)
06-01 20:58:47.344: E/AndroidRuntime(19920):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
06-01 20:58:47.344: E/AndroidRuntime(19920):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-01 20:58:47.344: E/AndroidRuntime(19920):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-01 20:58:47.344: E/AndroidRuntime(19920):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
06-01 20:58:47.344: E/AndroidRuntime(19920):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-01 20:58:47.344: E/AndroidRuntime(19920):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-01 20:58:47.344: E/AndroidRuntime(19920):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-01 20:58:47.344: E/AndroidRuntime(19920):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
06-01 20:58:47.344: E/AndroidRuntime(19920):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I hope you can say me whether i have to add some permissions or what else could be the problem.

Comment: Are you actually using this url: `https://plus.google.com/XXX`?

Comment: no the XXX is for any profil (i do not want to make it public - therefor the XXX)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why, but `Intent.createChooser()` seems to be the culprit. `startActivity(intent);` by itself should work.